# Extract data from a String, inc 2 lookups

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula

I am lookinng for an MS Excel formula that will allow me to extract some text from  a string. I have used LEFT/RIGHT/MID/FIND in other parts of my workbook, however I cannot find the correct formula for this particular string.

From the below string the text I need to extract is "Business One". The reason I am finding this difficult is because the text requried is to the right a s 2nd comma, so it's not just a case of looking for ","

Test Name, ID 12345, Business One^Business 2

Thank you

Comment: Look at SUBSTITUTE, it has an instance parameter.

Answer (score 0):

With your text in A1 try this,

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A1, FIND("^", A1), LEN(A1), ""), ", ", REPT(" ", LEN(A1))), LEN(A1)))
```

Comment: That has worked perfectly - Thank you so much for taking the time to help.